# Writing UNIX scripts that include "init"

Tags: unix, scripting

I have an install script for the operating system that I'm setting up and, in part of the script, I need to install the graphics card drivers. In order to do this, I'm required to switch to runlevel 2 using the command

```
init 2
```

So, if the script consists of

```
# In run level 3
echo "The";
init 2;
echo "quick";
init 3;
echo "brown";
```

, the only thing that is being printed is "The" due to the fact that the script is stopped in its tracks when the init command is sent. I'd like to make the installation of the operating system as automated as possible, but this seems to throw a wrench into the process. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general approach, what you could do is, in your script:

1. create an 'init script' named *scriptname* dynamically, with the commands you need to execute in that particular run level.
2. create the necessary symlinks from /etc/rc*runlevel*.d/S99*scriptname*.
3. switch to the runlevel by invoking init *runlevel*
4. init script *scriptname* will be executed
5. *scriptname* could disable itself after running by removing the symlink  /etc/rc*runlevel*.d/S99*scriptname*, and then repeat from 1 to 5.

It feels a bit ugly, but it does work (did it a long time ago).

Comment: Thank you! I'll be trying this out later today, but it seems like this  strategy should do the trick.